# CSS selector if sibling div overflows?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<!-- initial height is enough to show one line of text -->
<div id="div1"> some dynamic text </div>

   .
   .
   .

<!-- on clicking uses JS to set height of div1 to fit content
     only show if div1 has text overflowing -->
<div id="div2"> expand div1 </div>
```

Now, I want to show div2 only if div1 has enough text that it needs to be expanded, that is, if the content in div1 is overflowing. I know it can be achieved using JavaScript, but I want to know if it can be done using CSS exclusively.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

The text is dynamically fetched when a page is rendered. I can also not use media rules since the width at which I hide the expansion div is not fixed (the width threshold depends on the length of dynamic text which changes on each render)

Comment: There is no selector for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display read more button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817910/display-read-more-button)

Comment: @AdamP. No, I can't use JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) mentioned there is no selector for overflow detection. What you try to do is currently **not possible** using CSS only.

Additionally there is a GitHub issue with proposal to add such selector, but probably it will be closed with `WON'T FIX`

Mentioned GitHub issue: [link](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2011)

Related stack question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213197/is-there-a-css-pseudo-selector-for-overflow)